# How convert an OMA-DM protocol message to an LWM2M message?

Tags: iot, mdm, lwm2m, oma-dm

I am working on a device management solution for an IoT device. The device will host an LWM2M client. A gateway device (currently an Intel Galileo board), will host an OMA-DM client and a LWM2M server.

The general scenario is that the nodes should be  able to be managed by any OMA-DM or LWM2M compliant device management server.

In case of an OMA-DM server, the commands will be sent to the gateway where they will be received by an OMA-DM client and passed on to the nodes directly as LWM2M commands or the client will use the APIs of the LWM2M server to create and send the message/command.

As such I wanted to know if there is any solution currently available that can help with this.

OR

Are there any guides or papers or any information of any kind to help me implement this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMA has something called the LwM2M gateway which interfaces an OMA-DM server to an LwM2M Server.  So check out the MAI (Mobile Application Interface) gateway specs (which I don't think are finalized yet).